# call value of a variable from php page by ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to javascript and I've searched this question everywhere but no suitable answer.
I have a "code.php" page as

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[1];
```

On the other side in "index.php" i have

```
<h1>"the value for number is: " <span id="myText"></span></h1>

function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = $row[1];
}
```

I want to load the value of `$row[1]`  from `code.php` to `index.php`.

I know that i have to use ajax but how?

Comment: You could use jquery, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.

Comment: No it is returning nothing. It just says "the value for number is: "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In index php use ajax to get data from code php.
this is example :

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'code.php',
    type:'get',
    success:function(data){
      $("#myText").html(data);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  

    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'code.php',
        success:function(response){
    // ajax will assign the result of code =,php into response
      document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = response; //response;
        }
      });
});


 </script>
```

Place this  at header of your index.php

You can find more tutorials on line to get more understanding of ajax

dont forget to download jquery and embed it your code 
https://jquery.com/download/

Or u can  copy this 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">`